# How do I dynamically attach event handlers to SVG groups?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, svg

Adding event handlers to SVG groups (<g> tags) is resulting in strange behaviors.  It appears to be broken.  Here's the relevant code:

```
var newelement = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'use');
newelement.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', "#Xprototype");
var newgroup = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'g');
newgroup.appendChild(newelement);
newgroup.setAttribute("transform", "translate(100, 100)");
var svg = document.getElementById("thesvg");
newgroup.addEventListener("click", elementClick, false); //Click handler is set to the GROUP, not the element
svg.appendChild(newgroup);
```

Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/3bey8heu/2/

I have no problem adding event handlers to other objects - it seems to be unique to dynamically created groups.  And yes, groups can handle mouse events, as seen in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ZLnJw/) fiddle.

Comment: Probably because X is the only clickable thing inside the group. Try giving it a background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Only graphics elements can be the target of pointer-events such as click](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/interact.html#hit-testing). If you set it on a parent such as a `<g>` element then all its graphical children become possible targets but not the `<g>` itself.